# Quero pegar multiplos checkbox com ids de items para AJAX em select all

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um checkbox de selecionar tudo.

Embaixo dele tenho dois checkbox.

**O selecionar tudo eu não fiz ainda mas não é o problema, eu preciso só que, ao clicar no botão, envie o post com todos os checkbox selecionados!**

Código do botão para envio do AJAX:

```
<button onclick="checkbox_items_select_all_javascript();">enviar selecionados</button>
```

O botão vai capturar pelo JavaScript quais os items abaixo (checkbox) estão selecionados, e enviar como post para o arquivo PHP (AJAX)

Tentei o código deste tópico e não consegui fazer funcionar!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493531/send-multiple-checkbox-data-to-php-via-jquery-ajax#

Meus dois checkbox (item 1 e item 2 de exemplo)

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_items[]' id='select_{$anuncio['id']}' value='{$anuncio['id']}' >
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_items[]' id='select_{$anuncio['id']}' value='{$anuncio['id']}' >
```

Meu ajax:

```
function checkbox_items_select_all_javascript() {
    var checkbox_items = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
       checkbox_items = data['checkbox_items[]'].push($(this).val());
    });

  var dataString = 'checkbox_items='+ checkbox_items;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "aj/checkbox_items_select_all_ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
       alert(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Erro JavaScript (console):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement. (checkbox_items_select_all_javascript.js:4)
>       at Function.each (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2)
>       at checkbox_items_select_all_javascript (checkbox_items_select_all_javascript.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1) mais_opcoes.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Answer (score 3):

Esse `data['checkbox_items[]']` não existe. Você deveria fazer o `.push()` no `checkbox_items` que é uma array.

Não precisa, neste caso, usar array no `name`. Na verdade nem precisam de `name` os checkboxes (talvez nem de `id`), basta:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='select_{$anuncio['id']}' value='{$anuncio['id']}' >
<input type='checkbox' id='select_{$anuncio['id']}' value='{$anuncio['id']}' >
```

E na função você vai fazer:

```
var checkbox_items = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
   checkbox_items.push($(this).val());
});
```

Vai adicionar cada `value` de cada checkbox checado na array `checkbox_items`.

O resultado no PHP (`$_POST['checkbox_items']`) será uma string com os values separados por vírgula, algo como:

```
"valor1,valor2"
```

Que você pode converter em array com `explode()`:

```
explode(",", $_POST['checkbox_items']);
```